# Visual Studio Code doesn't stop at breakpoints, PHPDebug/XDebug

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug, breakpoints

**Hello community!**

I have a issue with my **PHP Debug** on **Visual Studio Code** (VSC). **VSC** doesn't stop on any breakpoints settled in my script. I have checked the port 9000. It's open when I run the **PHP Debug** in my **VSC**. Looking to the log it's seems that **XDebug** works, but **VSC** anyway doesn't stop on breakpoints.

Just in case if port **9000** is used by another application, I tried to change it to **9001** in **php.ini** and **launch.json**, and then I have restarted **Apache** to update **PHP configuration**, but **VSC** anyway doesn't stop on breakpoints.

I have tried to install another version of **extension of PHP Debug**, but that didn't fix my issue.

Any suggestions and/or advice are welcome. Details follow below. Reinstalling of **VSC** also did not bring me good news.

Thank you!

[You can see my breakpoint here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsMwu.png)

**Script:**

```php
<?php

  $i=0;
  $i=2;

  exit("\$i = $i end at ".date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));

?>
```

All installed stuff on my laptop:

```
macOS Catalina 10.15.3
XAMPP 5.6.40 Revision 1 with PHP5.6 and XDebug 2.2.5
Visual Studio Code 1.43.0 with PHP Debug 1.14.0
```

**XDebug** settings **php.ini**:

```
zend_extension=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_host = localhost
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.show_local_vars = 1
xdebug.remote_log = /Applications/XAMPP/logs/xdebug.log
```

**PHP Debug** settings **launch.json**:

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Listen for XDebug",
      "type": "php",
      "request": "launch",
      "port": 9000
    },
    {
      "name": "Launch currently open script",
      "type": "php",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${file}",
      "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
      "port": 9000
    }
  ]
}
```

**XDebug** logs:

```
Log opened at 2020-03-14 03:38:14
I: Connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9000.
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///Users/User888/Lab/backoffice/ping.php" language="PHP" protocol_version="1.0" appid="48376" idekey="User888"><engine version="2.2.5"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2014 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

<- breakpoint_list -i 1
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_list" transaction_id="1"></response>

<- breakpoint_set -i 2 -t line -f file:///Users/User888/Lab/BackOffice/ping.php -n 4
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="2" id="483760002"></response>

<- breakpoint_list -i 3
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_list" transaction_id="3"><breakpoint type="line" filename="file:///Users/User888/Lab/BackOffice/ping.php" lineno="4" state="enabled" hit_count="0" hit_value="0" id="483760002"></breakpoint></response>

<- breakpoint_list -i 4
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_list" transaction_id="4"><breakpoint type="line" filename="file:///Users/User888/Lab/BackOffice/ping.php" lineno="4" state="enabled" hit_count="0" hit_value="0" id="483760002"></breakpoint></response>

<- run -i 5
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="5" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

<- stop -i 6
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stop" transaction_id="6" status="stopped" reason="ok"></response>

Log closed at 2020-03-14 03:38:14
```

Comment: `echo` ing the phpinfo should have a section for xdebug(if configured correctly). Have you checked those? Also the vscode extention phpDebug have some recomendation on configuring xdebug. Try those as well. I have been using it for quite some time and haven’t had any issue. But I am not in front of my PC now. But i remember i just followed their instruction exactly like they recommended.